# How to fix noise in my bedroom since change of furance/ac but not air ducts?

Tags: ducts, central-heating

I had furnace company back out and he told me it is probably a problem with a damper but it would be hard to find out where.  It is only loud in my room on second floor but not in other bedroom next to mine.  It is waking me up at night and I need to find out what to do.  Will air duct cleaning place come out be able to solve?  I vacuumed all ducts myself when we got new furnace-could this have caused the problem??  I really need to get this fixed!  Thanks

Comment: Can you describe the nature of the noise?  That would help to narrow the possibilities.

Comment: It sounds like metal rattling.  At first I thought it sounded like a screw, nail, something metal sitting in there and rattling when furnace comes on and blows air thru the ducts.  Heating guy thought it was a damper but that would be hard to pinpoint where???   Thanks